# How do you change text color in Visual Studio 2019 back to original color?

Tags: visual-studio

So I have been using Visual Studio 2017 for a while, but recently installed Visual Studio 2019.  I noticed that in Visual Studio 2019, the code is colored differently.  How can this be changed back to the original color scheme?